# TcpClient distribution over ports

Tags: c#, port, tcpclient, tcplistener

Is there any difference between listening 1 port for 3000 TcpClients and listening 100 ports for 30 TcpClients.

Comment: Difference in what terms? Performance?

Comment: Well clearly there's a difference of "in one case you only have one port open". Sorry, it's really not clear what you're trying to ask here...

Comment: Let's say there is an heavy traffic between client and server. Does traffic becomes comfortable when i distribute clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on your TCP server you would be opening 1 listening socket vs. 100.  Managing 100 listening ports would be difficult.

The amount of TCP traffic would be the same, as you have the same number of connections in each scenario, but you'll have more overhead with managing so many different sockets.

If your goal is to spread out the load on the server, creating additional listening ports is not really the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thats a bit Correct ,managing so many ports are difficult. but opening single port for so many for eg 1 serversocket for 3000 clients will surely degrade the performance and make lot of delay.

Now if two clients send data simultaneously, server can only process them sequentially. So second client won't get processed until server is done processing with first.
```